# raise exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError(_CLOUD_SDK_MISSING_CREDENTIALS)

Tags: langchain

I'm trying to get Langchain to connect Google Drive to Chat GPT but I cannot seem to get the program to find the credentials.

Here is the error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Projects\drive2chat\chat2drive.py", line 13, in 
docs = loader.load()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\mitch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\langchain\document_loaders\googledrive.py", line 350, in load
return self._load_documents_from_folder(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\mitch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\langchain\document_loaders\googledrive.py", line 235, in _load_documents_from_folder
creds = self._load_credentials()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\mitch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\langchain\document_loaders\googledrive.py", line 139, in _load_credentials
creds, project = default()
^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\mitch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\google\auth_default.py", line 697, in default
raise exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError(_CLOUD_SDK_MISSING_CREDENTIALS)
google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: Your default credentials were not found. To set up Application Default Credentials, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/external/set-up-adc for more information.

I think I understand the error and I am pretty sure I have the json file in the right place. I've even tried hard coding the filepath into PATH but still get the same error.

The code:

```
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.chains import RetrievalQA
from langchain.document_loaders import GoogleDriveLoader
from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter
from langchain.embeddings import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain.vectorstores import Chroma

folder_id = "1rrNqljxwmGVrubZeR2FNMxZJSi5Eh95V"
loader = GoogleDriveLoader(
    folder_id=folder_id,
    recursive=False
)
docs = loader.load()

text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(
    chunk_size=4000, chunk_overlap=0, separators=[" ", ",", "\n"]
    )

texts = text_splitter.split_documents(docs)
embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings()
db = Chroma.from_documents(texts, embeddings)
retriever = db.as_retriever()

llm = ChatOpenAI(temperature=0, model_name="gpt-3.5-turbo")
qa = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(llm=llm, chain_type="stuff", retriever=retriever)

while True:
    query = input("> ")
    answer = qa.run(query)
    print(answer)
```

And the code for the function that throws the error:

```
def default(scopes=None, request=None, quota_project_id=None, default_scopes=None):
    print("Line 545")
    """Gets the default credentials for the current environment.

    `Application Default Credentials`_ provides an easy way to obtain
    credentials to call Google APIs for server-to-server or local applications.
    This function acquires credentials from the environment in the following
    order:

    1. If the environment variable ``GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`` is set
       to the path of a valid service account JSON private key file, then it is
       loaded and returned. The project ID returned is the project ID defined
       in the service account file if available (some older files do not
       contain project ID information).

       If the environment variable is set to the path of a valid external
       account JSON configuration file (workload identity federation), then the
       configuration file is used to determine and retrieve the external
       credentials from the current environment (AWS, Azure, etc).
       These will then be exchanged for Google access tokens via the Google STS
       endpoint.
       The project ID returned in this case is the one corresponding to the
       underlying workload identity pool resource if determinable.

       If the environment variable is set to the path of a valid GDCH service
       account JSON file (`Google Distributed Cloud Hosted`_), then a GDCH
       credential will be returned. The project ID returned is the project
       specified in the JSON file.
    2. If the `Google Cloud SDK`_ is installed and has application default
       credentials set they are loaded and returned.

       To enable application default credentials with the Cloud SDK run::

            gcloud auth application-default login

       If the Cloud SDK has an active project, the project ID is returned. The
       active project can be set using::

            gcloud config set project

    3. If the application is running in the `App Engine standard environment`_
       (first generation) then the credentials and project ID from the
       `App Identity Service`_ are used.
    4. If the application is running in `Compute Engine`_ or `Cloud Run`_ or
       the `App Engine flexible environment`_ or the `App Engine standard
       environment`_ (second generation) then the credentials and project ID
       are obtained from the `Metadata Service`_.
    5. If no credentials are found,
       :class:`~google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError` will be raised.

    .. _Application Default Credentials: https://developers.google.com\
            /identity/protocols/application-default-credentials
    .. _Google Cloud SDK: https://cloud.google.com/sdk
    .. _App Engine standard environment: https://cloud.google.com/appengine
    .. _App Identity Service: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python\
            /appidentity/
    .. _Compute Engine: https://cloud.google.com/compute
    .. _App Engine flexible environment: https://cloud.google.com\
            /appengine/flexible
    .. _Metadata Service: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs\
            /storing-retrieving-metadata
    .. _Cloud Run: https://cloud.google.com/run
    .. _Google Distributed Cloud Hosted: https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics\
            /hybrid-cloud/announcing-google-distributed-cloud-edge-and-hosted

    Example::

        import google.auth

        credentials, project_id = google.auth.default()

    Args:
        scopes (Sequence[str]): The list of scopes for the credentials. If
            specified, the credentials will automatically be scoped if
            necessary.
        request (Optional[google.auth.transport.Request]): An object used to make
            HTTP requests. This is used to either detect whether the application
            is running on Compute Engine or to determine the associated project
            ID for a workload identity pool resource (external account
            credentials). If not specified, then it will either use the standard
            library http client to make requests for Compute Engine credentials
            or a google.auth.transport.requests.Request client for external
            account credentials.
        quota_project_id (Optional[str]): The project ID used for
            quota and billing.
        default_scopes (Optional[Sequence[str]]): Default scopes passed by a
            Google client library. Use 'scopes' for user-defined scopes.
    Returns:
        Tuple[~google.auth.credentials.Credentials, Optional[str]]:
            the current environment's credentials and project ID. Project ID
            may be None, which indicates that the Project ID could not be
            ascertained from the environment.

    Raises:
        ~google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError:
            If no credentials were found, or if the credentials found were
            invalid.
    """
    from google.auth.credentials import with_scopes_if_required
    from google.auth.credentials import CredentialsWithQuotaProject
    print("Line 643")
    explicit_project_id = os.environ.get(
        environment_vars.PROJECT, os.environ.get(environment_vars.LEGACY_PROJECT)
    )

    checkers = (
        # Avoid passing scopes here to prevent passing scopes to user credentials.
        # with_scopes_if_required() below will ensure scopes/default scopes are
        # safely set on the returned credentials since requires_scopes will
        # guard against setting scopes on user credentials.
        lambda: _get_explicit_environ_credentials(quota_project_id=quota_project_id),
        lambda: _get_gcloud_sdk_credentials(quota_project_id=quota_project_id),
        _get_gae_credentials,
        lambda: _get_gce_credentials(request, quota_project_id=quota_project_id),
    )
    print("line 658>>> " +  " <<<<")
    for checker in checkers:
        credentials, project_id = checker()
        print("credentials: " )
        if credentials is not None:
            print("line 662")
            credentials = with_scopes_if_required(
                
                credentials, scopes, default_scopes=default_scopes
            )

            # For external account credentials, scopes are required to determine
            # the project ID. Try to get the project ID again if not yet
            # determined.
            if not project_id and callable(
                getattr(credentials, "get_project_id", None)
            ):
                if request is None:
                    import google.auth.transport.requests

                    request = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
                project_id = credentials.get_project_id(request=request)

            if quota_project_id and isinstance(
                credentials, CredentialsWithQuotaProject
            ):
                credentials = credentials.with_quota_project(quota_project_id)

            effective_project_id = explicit_project_id or project_id
            if not effective_project_id:
                _LOGGER.warning(
                    "No project ID could be determined. Consider running "
                    "`gcloud config set project` or setting the %s "
                    "environment variable",
                    environment_vars.PROJECT,
                )
            return credentials, effective_project_id

    raise exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError(_CLOUD_SDK_MISSING_CREDENTIALS)
```